# How to get data about state which is currently hovered? Plotly Choropleth - USA map

Tags: python, plotly, choropleth

I created an interactive map of individual US states. The map will contain information on electric vehicles in the US. Currently, it is colored depending on the range (average in kilometers) of a given vehicle.

---

**Here is my code:**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/AlbertKozera/6396b4333d1a9222193e11401069ed9a/raw/ab8733a2135bcf61999bbcac4f92e0de5fd56794/Pojazdy%2520elektryczne%2520w%2520USA.csv')

for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].astype(str)
df['range'] = pd.to_numeric(df['range'])
df_range = df.drop(columns = ['state', 'brand', 'model', 'year of production', 'type']).groupby('code', as_index=False)
df_range_mean = df_range.agg({'range':'mean'})

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Choropleth(
    locations=df['code'].drop_duplicates(keep='first').reset_index(drop=True),
    z = round(df_range_mean['range'], 2),
    locationmode='USA-states',
    colorscale='Reds',
    autocolorscale=False,
    marker_line_color='black',
))

fig.update_layout(   
    geo = dict(
        scope='usa',
        projection=go.layout.geo.Projection(type = 'albers usa'),
        showlakes=True, # lakes
        lakecolor='rgb(255, 255, 255)'),
)

fig.show()
```

---

**It looks like this:**
[image]

---

***Here is my question:***

---

I need to dynamically return information about the given state in which the mouse cursor is currently located. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do it and whether it is possible at all. I have to implement a method that will display a different image (chernoff face) depending on what state is currently highlighted by the user.
**Can anyone tell me if there is any method that will return data about the currently highlighted state?** Or maybe, unfortunately - I will have to write my own listener.
I was searching such a method in documentation but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

The argument `locations=df['state']`  into the go.Choropleth function should return the abbreviation of the state you refer whenever you point the cursor.